# How many times are executed the programs invoked by execl?

Tags: c, process, exec, fork

Can you help me with this?
How many times are executed the programs "exam" and "students" invoked by execl? I think the correct answer is 8 runtimes for program "exam" and 0 for "students", because in the two first forks will be created 3 child processes, after that in loop the first fork() will create more 4 processes, since the three children already created also will run this code, thereafter we have a exec that will replace the current code of the 7 processes created and of the actual program and run it(program "exam") 8 times. My reasoning is correct?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    pid_t
    pid=fork(); 
    pid=fork();

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){ 
        pid=fork();
        execlp("exam","exam",NULL);
        if(pid==0){
            break;
        }
    }
    execlp("students", "students","sistcomp",NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just add some `printf`s and run it?

Comment: Run it and find out? From a glance, *at least* 1 process will "fall through" to "students"

Comment: @JonathonReinhart because that requires work - something that the OP wishes to avoid.  Why bother with work if you can con some other sucker to do it for you?

Comment: @MartinJames I'm just trying to figure out if my reasoning is correct, you needn't be arrogant, comments like that are unnecessary

Comment: @SérgioGomes Your reasoning looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you are right. Let me draw a diagram to explain:

```
        +---1 ...                                       
        |                                            
    +---+---2 ...                                       
    |                                                
----+---+---3 ...                                       
  fork()|                                            
        +---4+----  execlp("exam","exam",NULL);
      fork() |                                        
             +----  execlp("exam","exam",NULL);
        ^                                             
        after the first two fork()
```

you see, after 2 `fork()`, we get 4 process. Take the No.4 as an example, it enter `for` loop and `fork()` again, then we get another child process here, this child process and its father will exec `execlp("exam","exam",NULL);` as you see this will replace the current code.The same is true for No.1, No.2 and No.3.

So, it will be 8 runtimes for program "exam" and 0 for "students".

But, when you run this code, runtimes for program "exam" may be 7 or 6, it may be caused by [Copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)(I am not pretty sure about this)

PS:
It is a good practice to use `execlp` like this:

```
if (pid == 0)           
   execlp("exam","exam",NULL);
```

or

```
if (pid != 0)           
    execlp("exam","exam",NULL);
```

Comment: `if (pid != 0) execlp("exam","exam",NULL);` doesn't check for errors from fork.